# Expression is not a method VS2010

Tags: vb.net

I get the error "Expression is not a method VS2010" from the following code:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    conn.ConnectionString = connstring

    If Not conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        *ConnectionState*.Open()

        MsgBox("open")
    Else
        MsgBox("close")
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should be `conn.Open`:

```
If Not conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
    conn.Open()
    MsgBox("open")
Else
    MsgBox("close")
End If
```

[ConnectionState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.connectionstate.aspx) is an enumeration, not a variable.